# Plotly autorange axes setting

Tags: python, visualization, plotly

I have one question for plotly x and y axes setting.

It's possible to autorange the axis only the first time based on all input data and then turn off rescaling while manipulating the data input (in the legend)?

> https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-xaxis-type
>
> From documentation: 'autorange' default: True 
>   Determines whether or not the range of this axis is computed in relation to the input data.

I need autorange only to be done first time and then it should behave like False. I need it so I can make evaluations relative to the whole dataset. 
Maybe it can be done another way, not by manipulating autorange but that's why I'm asking.

MY EXAMPLE:

Imagine you have visualization like this. I have labeled many groups so that I can turn them off/on by plotly functionality. But the problem for me is that it is rescaling everytime based on the input data (only the ones which are 'turned on').

[image: My visualization]
This is after I isolate the GROUP 1. But I want the same x-axis and y-axis as I had before (which was 'autoranged' when I started the visualization).
[image: My visualization2]

Thanks for your help!